# Simple Java client and server socket setup breaks message loop after one iteration

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have a very simple client/server setup as a type of "Guess the word" game. The server prompts the client to guess a word, the client enters their guess and sends it back to the server, if the guess is incorrect the server will send the first letter of the word, then second, and so on for each incorrect guess. This loop is supposed to continue until the client guesses the word or types 'Bye.'.

The issue with my code is that the first loop will work only. Then it stops functioning. I've tried adjusting the while loop setup, switching between while(input.readLine() != null) or while(true) but it just will not work.

Client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatchingClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String hostName = "localhost";
        int portNum = 8015;

        try (
                Socket guessSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNum);
                PrintWriter output =
                        new PrintWriter(guessSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader input =
                        new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(guessSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String fromServer;
            System.out.println(input.readLine());
            while (true) {
                String msg = scanner.nextLine();
                output.println(msg);
                while ((fromServer = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(fromServer);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MatchingServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String guess = "java";
        int portNum = 8015;
        try (
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNum);
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                PrintWriter output =
                        new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ){
            // Initiate conversation with client
            System.out.println("Client connected");
            output.println("Make a guess: ");
            int counter = 0;
            String clientResponse;
            String serverReponse;

                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Test");
                    clientResponse = input.readLine();
                    if (clientResponse.equals("Bye.") || clientResponse.equals("java")) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        serverReponse = "Guess again";
                        serverReponse += "\nHere's a hint\n";
                        serverReponse += guess.charAt(counter);
                        output.println(serverReponse);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                    + portNum + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `while ((fromServer = input.readLine()) != null) {System.out.println(fromServer); }` this just loops reading lines from the server and printing them until the socket closes. I don't know what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk That was my intention, for the client to loop reading lines received from the server until all lines were read. Then after all the lines were read, break the loop so the client could 'guess' again. I'm a novice at socket programming though, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a small design issue in your program. When clients and servers talk to each other, there should be a **protocol**, that is, a message structure using which it becomes clear when the remote application has completed its message. Otherwise, you may end up waiting on the input stream when nothing is being sent. That is what is happening here.

So, here is a changed code for only the communication part in your classes. The server will end its message with the word `over`. When the client sees the word, it doesn't try to read from the socket input anymore.

The exact lines added are commented with `CHANGED`.

### Server

```java
while( true ){
    System.out.println( "Test" );
    clientResponse = input.readLine();
    if( clientResponse.equals( "Bye." ) || clientResponse.equals( "java" ) ){
        break;
    }
    else{
        serverReponse = "Guess again\n";
        serverReponse += "Here's a hint\n";

        /* CHANGED: 
         * (a) A newline after the hint character
         * (b) Add a message completion marker that the client also understands. */
        serverReponse += guess.charAt( counter ) + "\n";
        serverReponse += "over";
        output.println( serverReponse );
        counter++;
    }
}
```

### Client

```java
while (true) {
    String msg = scanner.nextLine();
    output.println(msg);
    while ((fromServer = input.readLine()) != null) {
        /* CHANGED: If the response is completed, break and to go back to accepting the user input. */
        if( fromServer.equalsIgnoreCase( "over" ) ) break;
        System.out.println(fromServer);
    }
}
```